How do I embed, or iframe a google doodle, such as google baseball, or google cricket on my website?
I need help embedding games, such as doodle's on my game site, including doodle snake, google baseball, google cricket, memory game, etc.
I have tried to iframe the url, and paste the whole source code, and I tried to find an iframe in the source code, but unfortunately, I could not find anything related to embedding doodles.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
